# using ref to delete Node in the middle of a linked list, given only access to that node

Tags: c#, .net, linked-list, ref

I have the solution. So I do not need help, but I have a question. This code works:

```
public void Delete(ref Node n)
{
    n = n.next;
}

LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
list.AddTail(4);
list.AddTail(3);
list.AddTail(2);
list.AddTail(1);
list.AddTail(0);

list.Delete(ref list.head.next.next);
```

But this code does not:

```
Node n = list.head.next.next;
list.Delete(ref n);
```

Why?

EDIT:

```
public class Node
{
    public int number;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int number, Node next)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: in what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Doesn't give any errors. It just doesn't do anything.

Comment: What LinkedList are you using?

Comment: @SimonKarlsson My own implementation. I am practicing algorithms.

Comment: @Orvel then please provide the implementation of your delete

Comment: @SimonKarlsson I did. The Delete method is in the code

Comment: @thumbmunkeys No, it's a class. I will add code.

Comment: I _think_ it's not working because in the first case you are changing the `next` property of `list.head.next` but in the second case you are just changing the node that your local variable `n` is referencing.

Comment: You might want to read [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet.

Comment: All the `ref` keyword does is to not pass a copy.  But when you do `Node n = list.head.next.next;` you are making a copy.

Comment: @juharr Well, you are not using the new keyword. So a new object is not being created.

Comment: @Orvel There isn't a new object, there's a copy of the reference to the same object.  It's like you have you address written on a piece of paper.  Then I copy that onto another piece of paper.  If I then change the address on my piece of paper it doesn't change the address on your piece of paper and it certainly doesn't effect your house.

Comment: @SimonKarlsson Why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
list.Delete(ref list.head.next.next);
```

You change reference (pointer) to field List.next.

But if you call

```
list.Delete(ref n);
```

You change reference (pointer) of local variable.

**Just try to inline you code:**

```
list.Delete(ref list.head.next.next);
```

looks like

```
list.head.next.next = list.head.next.next.next;
```

But

```
Node n = list.head.next.next; 
list.Delete(ref n);
```

looks like

```
Node n = list.head.next.next; 
n = n.next;
```